# Htaccess language redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Please help, I have a website where English is the main language

It has language folders:

```
/de
/es
/it
/fr
```

There is no en English folder as I have the English as the main domain so English files are in public HTML folder

I have the htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}          ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(it|fr|de|es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

This works perfectly apart from this bug
There is a loop

If the language browser is NOT English but Spanish or French etc they cannot click the English flag to take them to the English version which is the main domain with no subfolder  it simply redirects loops them back to their own language

Is there simple way to fix this without creating /en ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what I suggest is setting `?lang=en` on your link to English and changing your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=lang=en
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(it|fr|de|es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/ [L,R]
```

And also changing the redirect to temporary, which I did above, or the redirect will have been cached in their browser.

I removed the request_uri check as it's already checked in your RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks will try it, not sure I completely understand but will try!